# how to delete sharedpreference after 60minutes

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I want to store login data but I want that data to be deleted after 60 minutes.
What is the proper way to do this?

The app can be closed, stopped, opened in these 60 minutes.
I don't want to use an internal database.

Here is my code for accessing `SharedPreferences`

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(Username, usernameTxt);
editor.putString(Password, passwordTxt);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest and most direct way to do this is keeping expired date:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("Username", usernameTxt);
editor.putString("Password", passwordTxt);
editor.putLong("ExpiredDate", System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(60));
editor.apply();
```

And then check it

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (sharedpreferences.getLong("ExpiredDate", -1) > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    // read email and password
} else {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
}
```

But, @CommonsWare is right and keeping the information just in your process is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not implement it that way. Keep the information just in your process, so that the data goes away when your process does.

That being said, you are welcome to use `JobScheduler` or `AlarmManager` to schedule work to be done in the future, regardless of the state of your app at that time.

Comment: i checked these two options and I have to say my API limit is 16, and these two are 19 and greater. can't use them

Comment: 19 and greater? What? AlarmManager was added in API level 1, the very first version of Android, ever. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html